# Google sheet: splitting dataset rows based on comma separated values in one column and replicating all other columns

Tags: google-sheets, split, array-formulas, flatten

I am collecting data from a Google form (data stored to a Google sheet) and to improve data collection some fields may contain multiple values (through checkboxes in the form).

[Original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeOMy.jpg)

For analysis purposes, whenever there are multiple values in **two **separate columns, I would like to split the row: separate the multiple values one by row and just replicate all other columns. Like this:

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8KS8.jpg)

**First**, based on many searches and suggestions, particularly on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71382735/google-sheets-duplicating-rows-by-splitting-comma-separated-multiple-values) I have managed to achieve the desired output when splitting **only by one column**

[Works when splitting by one column ONLY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrROk.jpg)

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(A3:A7, ","))&"×"&B3:B7&"×"&C3:C7&"×"&D3:D7), "×", 0, 0),  "where Col1 is not null"))`

**Second**: However, following the same source, I tried to split also by another column (Col3).
It works very poorly, there are missing combinations and some undesired output.

[Current output, with missing lines and undesired parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmKAK.jpg)

**Third**, I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63193639/how-do-you-separate-comma-separated-values-in-different-columns-while-maintainin)  and tried to paste the proposed formula in a Sheet2 in the sample sheet linked below. Still not working, too complex for me.

This is a sample Google sheet replicating the main issue, showing the desired output, the correct splitting by one column, and the current unsatisfactory situation for two columns,
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qk-T4QuFTCcWpqNN9odCbNhLD_MjZZtLs7ZO3fhrslM/edit?usp=sharing

thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=index(let(a,query(split(flatten(B3:B7&"|"&C3:C7&"|"&D3:D7&"|"&split(A3:A7,", ")),"|",0,0),"Where Col4<>''"),
query(split(flatten(index(a,,4)&"|"&index(a,,1)&"|"&index(a,,3)&"|"&split(index(a,,2),", ")),"|",0,0),"Select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col3 Where Col4<>''")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solution works well. I had posted this also on Google Docs Editors help and a very effective custom formula was suggested. See https://support.google.com/docs/thread/205336269?hl=en&msgid=205347476